# Rewrite rule on .htaccess with pattern match containing dot character is not working

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Im creating a site with htaccess and one of the following it's not working by bringing up an error in the browser:

```
The page isn't redirecting properly
```

The rewrite rule line is:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-_\.]+)$      index.php?user=$1   [NC,L]
```

I'm using it to get user profile in a get variable, the problem seems to be solved if the dot character is removed like this:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-_]+)$      index.php?user=$1   [NC,L]
```

But i need the username format to contain the dot character.

**Examples of how it should work:**

```
http://www.example.dev/john.88     >>>  index.php?user=john.88
http://www.example.dev/johnsmith   >>>  index.php?user=johnsmith
http://www.example.dev/john_smith  >>>  index.php?user=john_smith
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The new URL also matches the expression, so you get an infinite loop. It isn't related to the dot, you could also remove letter `e` :)

Comment: The rewrite rule i'm using is used as last rule, removing the dot works fine without causing any loop. What do you mean remove letter **e** ?

Comment: `index.php?user=$1` matches `^([a-zA-Z0-9-_]+)$`. If you remove the dot you get an expression it no longer matches (`^([a-zA-Z0-9-_]+)$`) but the same happen if you remove any other letter in `index.php?user=$1` (e.g. `^([a-df-zA-Z0-9-_\.]+)$`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With DOT in pattern it will indeed cause infinite loop as rewritten URI `/index.php` also matches your pattern.

To fix this you need `RewriteCond`:

```
# If the request is not for a valid directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# If the request is not for a valid file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([\w.-]+)/?$ index.php?user=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Also note your regex pattern can be shortened by using `\w` which is equivalent of `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`